# Stop a Execute Callback Function - MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, timer, callback

i check every two seconds if a EXE is running. If its not running then check in a .mat file a value. If value is 1 then the program should stop(t). At moment the stop(t) isnt working or if i leave it out then i have infinite loop.

```
t=timer;
t.period=2;
t.TasksToExecute=inf;
t.ExecutionMode='fixedRate';
t.TimerFcn=@check_exe;
start(t)

function check_exe(mTimer,~)

%check if EXE is already running
[~,b]=system('tasklist');
IsRunning=contains(b,'Digitale_Ablegeschablone');
    
    if IsRunning(1)
        fprintf('Digitale_Ablegeschablone ist bereits geöffnet!\n');
    else
        load('Parameter.mat', 'Speicherstatus')
        load('Parameter.mat', 'Block_beendet')
        load('Parameter.mat', 'Save_Session')
        
        if Save_Session==1
            fprintf('Sitzung ist gespeichert. Digitale Ablegeschablone wird nicht geöffnet\n');
            stop(t) %stop
        elseif Block_beendet==1
            fprintf('Sitzung ist beendet. Digitale Ablegeschablone wird nicht geöffnet\n');
            stop(t) %stop 
        else
            %start again (if its crashed)
            system('C:\Users\christian\Desktop\TEST\EXE\Digitale_Ablegeschablone.exe &')
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `stop(t)` inside a function which doesn't "know" what `t` is - it is not defined anywhere in the scope of that function, hence the error message you get

> Unrecognized function or variable 't'.

The first input to the callback function `check_exe`, which you're not using at all currently, is actually the timer object. However, you've called it `mTimer` instead of `t`. You need to either use `stop(mTimer)` or change the input name to `t`. A simpler complete example which just checks if some test file exists can be used to test this:

```
function check(t,~)
    if exist( 'C:\Users\wfeavyou\Desktop\test.txt', 'file' )
        fprintf( 'Stopping at time=%dsec!\n', (t.TasksExecuted-1)*t.Period );
        stop(t) %stop 
    else
        fprintf( 'Check failed, continuing at time=%dsec!\n', (t.TasksExecuted-1)*t.Period );
    end
end
```

This produces the following output where I manually made the `test.txt` file after 6 seconds. I can't test it because your example isn't stand-alone, but it should work in the same way just by changing the first input name to `t`

```
Check failed, continuing at time=0sec!
Check failed, continuing at time=2sec!
Check failed, continuing at time=4sec!
Check failed, continuing at time=6sec!
Stopping at time=8sec!
```